# Issues when using pre-compiled regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, precompile

I am having some issues with matching when i try and implement pre-compiled regex in a Perl script.  I have the script working without pre-compiling, and any time I have an express that spans lines, it returns no match when pre-compiling.  So for example:

```
my $regex_partner = qr/<h1 id="PartnerName">(?<partner_name>.*?)<\/h1>/;
$content =~ $regex_partner;
$partner_name = $+{partner_name};
```

Works fine when pre-compiling, but:

```
my $regex_web =~ qr/Company Website:.*openWindow[(]'(?<website>http:\/\/.*?)'/s;
$content =~ $regex_web;
$website = $+{website};
```

returns nothing, but works if i take out the whole pre-compile.  It seems any time qr//s is used, it will not work.

help?

Comment: What version of Perl are you using?

Answer (score 9):

You have a typo.

```
my $regex_web =~ qr/.../s;
```

That should be:

```
my $regex_web = qr/.../s;
```

The former is performing a pattern match against `$regex_web`.  The latter is assigning the pattern to $regex_web.  If warnings were on you'd have gotten a "Use of uninitialized value $regex_web in pattern match" warning.

Unless it's a typo in your post?